# change default selected color on wia scanner dialog using c++

Tags: c++, scanning, wia

I'm using a wia scanner to scan documents using c++. I have got everything working but then I need the default color to be selected to greyscale and also the default paper size to be A4 on that drop down. Searched through the net and came up with nothing so far. 
I saw on Microsoft's page that to change the color you use WIA_IPS_CUR_INTENT -> WIA_INTENT_IMAGE_TYPE_GRAYSCALE and the WIA_IPS_PAGE_SIZE -> WIA_PAGE_A4. But that didn't seem to change the default selected color when i set those properties.

```
WriteProperty(device, WIA_IPS_PAGE_SIZE, WIA_PAGE_A4);
WriteProperty(device, WIA_IPS_CUR_INTENT, WIA_INTENT_IMAGE_TYPE_TEXT);
```

Any ideas or suggestions
Here is the dialog:  [wia dialog scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd2oE.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide a [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please ?. It's hard to tell what's going on without code.  You might have already read [this note from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wia/-wia-imageintentconstants).

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to set the **grayscale** color to be selected by default (instead of the "Color" option that's selected) on the scanner dialog on the "wia dialog scanner" link I attached above. I also want to default the image size to **A4** when the dialog opens. I've tried code above to write properties but didn't work